# How to turn the Lexical editor in read only mode

Tags: lexicaljs

I'm using the Lexical editor from Facebook and I'm having difficulties to set the editor into read only mode.

In order to try it, I'm setting the `readyOnly` property but no success:

```
 <ContentEditable readOnly={false} className="editor-input" />
```

Here's the full code

```
    <LexicalComposer initialConfig={editorConfig}>
      <div className="editor-container">
        <ToolbarPlugin />
        <div className="editor-inner">
          <RichTextPlugin
            contentEditable={
              <ContentEditable readOnly={true} className="editor-input" />
            }
            placeholder={<Placeholder />}
          />
          <HistoryPlugin />
          {/* <TreeViewPlugin />  */}
          <AutoFocusPlugin />
          <CodeHighlightPlugin />
          <ListPlugin />
          <LinkPlugin />
          <AutoLinkPlugin />
          <ListMaxIndentLevelPlugin maxDepth={7} />
          <MarkdownShortcutPlugin transformers={TRANSFORMERS} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <OnChangePlugin
        onChange={onChange}
        ignoreSelectionChange
        ignoreHistoryMergeTagChange
      />
      <TextLoader note={note} />
    </LexicalComposer>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it through the initialConfig like this

```
const editorConfig = {
   namespace: 'blahblah',
   editable: false,
   ....
}

<LexicalComposer initialConfig={editorConfig}
```